# Recursive Minimax Function for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, algorithm

I have recently being try to make a tic tac toe game using the mini max algorithm. I first created a board, then two player. Afterwards, I changed one of the players into the algorithm. I tried using something similar to this [javascript implementation](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/0zyUhZdJD).  **I am not getting an syntax error, just the algorithm is not working.**

For example, take the following game sequence.

1. The algorithm starts the game and places an "X" at the top right of the board or in index[0].
2. I, the player place "O" in the top right of the board or in index[2].
3. The algorithm  places an "X" at the top center of the board or in index [1].
4. I, the player place "O" in the middle center of the board or in index[4].
5. The algorithm places an "X" at the middle left of the board or in index [3].

**The error is that rather than stopping the win, the algorithm is playing the next free position.**

In the min-max algorithm, this is a minimizing agent (seeks the least score) and the maximizing agent (the higher score) (in this case the AI). Below is the code, can you help me find the issue? Or how should I go along? Because I have been trying for the last two days. Hopefully the explanation above made sense.

```python
board = ["."] * 9
winning_comb = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,4,6],[0,4,8]]
game = True


def new_board():
    print (board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print (board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print (board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])

new_board()
def winning(comb):
    global game
    for l in range(len(winning_comb)):
        a = winning_comb[l][0]
        f = winning_comb[l][1]
        v = winning_comb[l][2]
        if comb[a] == comb[f] == comb[v] == "O" or "x" == comb[a] == comb[f] == comb[v]:
            game = False
            if comb[a] == "x":
                return 1
            else:
                return -1
            break
        else:
            game = True


def minmax(board,depth, ismax):
    if winning(board) != None:
        h = winning(board)
        return h

    else:
        if ismax == True:
            bestscore = float('-inf')
            for k in range(len(board)):
                if board[k] == ".":
                    board[k] = "x"
                    score = minmax(board,depth+1,False)
                    board[k] = '.'
                    bestscore = max(bestscore, score)
            return bestscore
        else:
            bestscore = float('inf')
            for k in range(len(board)):
                if board[k] == ".":
                    board[k] = "O"
                    score = minmax(board,depth+1,True)
                    board[k] = '.'
                    bestscore = min(bestscore,score)
                return bestscore



def player1() :
    bestscore = float('-inf')
    bestmove = 0
    for k in range(len(board)):
        if board[k] == ".":
            board[k] = "x"
            score = minmax(board, 0, False)
            board[k] = "."
            if score > bestscore:
                bestscore = score
                bestmove = k
    board[bestmove] = "x"
    new_board()


def player2():
    number = int(input("Please enter your poistion?") )
    board[number - 1 ] = "O"
    new_board()
    winning(board)

while game==True:
    player1()
    player2()
```

Comment: [3,4,6] shouldn't be a winning combination. It should be [2,4,6]

Comment: @PeterCheng you should post that as an answer.  You are exactly right.  To it I would add that it is best to generate those conditions programmatically if possible rather than hard coding them exactly because it is easy to mess them up.

Answer (score 2):

[3,4,6] shouldn't be a winning combination. It should be [2,4,6]

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- `[3,4,6]` should be `[2,4,6]`
- Indentation of `return bestscore` is wrong in the second instance: currently it interrupts the loop.
- If you backtrack after `game = False` is executed, that assignment should be undone. For that reason it is probably easier to not use that variable at all, and just call the function `winning` when needed. The main loop could then be:

  ```
  while winning(board) is None:
      player1()
      if winning(board) is not None: # need to exit
          break
      player2()
  ```
- `bestscore` will be (-)infinity when there is no more free cell in the grid, and the game really is a draw. In that case `bestscore` should be 0, so this draw is considered better than a loss, and worse than a win. So make sure `winning` does not return `None` in that case, but 0:

  ```
  if not "." in comb:
      return 0
  ```
- Not an error, but it is a bit odd that some functions take the board as argument, and others not. Make this consistent, and always pass the board as argument (`player1(board)`, `player2(board)` and `winning(board)`).

With these changes, the AI will play the best play, although the calculation for the first move takes quite some time. You could improve by applying alpha-beta pruning.